# How to detect spelling mistake of template tag?

Tags: wordpress, misspelling

Does anyone know how to detect spelling mistake of template tag?

For example:

```
○ <?php the_permalink() ?>
✕ <?php the_premalink() ?>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Do you wanna detect syntactical errors related to the tag structure or variables and functions inside the tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best is to use a good IDE that will contain your whole project.
I use PHPStorm which makes this effortless. Highly recommended.
It will scan your whole project including Wordpress and will give you hints on each function you wish to put in your code.